# RealFavicon generator JSON could not be parsed. Check your syntax

Tags: javascript, favicon

I am trying to implement `https://realfavicongenerator.net/` to generate favicon in my application.

Request url works in new window but it gives json error in iframe or in a loaded div.
RequestURL:

```
https://realfavicongenerator.net/api/favicon_generator?json_params=%7B%22favicon_generation%22:%7B%22callback%22:%7B%22type%22:%22url%22,%22url%22:%22http://localhost:9003%22,%22custom_parameter%22:%22realFavIconResponse%22,%22short_url%22:false,%22path_only%22:false%7D,%22master_picture%22:%7B%22type%22:%22no_picture%22,%22demo%22:false%7D,%22files_location%22:%7B%22type%22:%22path%22,%22path%22:%22//images.oz.me/9243b7c6-3b49-4320-a2c5-d68aaf3d56c4/%22%7D,%22api_key%22:%22aa4143641ba2d58798874b1d6f2d39f41c00aa3e%22%7D%7D
```

jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/w3kjze94/

Any idea?
thanks

[image]

Comment: The site probably doesn't like being embedded...

Comment: @Cerbrus is right, the site wants you to open the site in its own window (tab), and then it'll redirect the user to the specified redirect URL once they're done ([source](https://realfavicongenerator.net/api#favicon-generation))